# UIView drag with finger and release like Instagram back swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have a **UIViewController** which displays content. Inside of it, I have an overlaying **UIView** named *contentView* which has a frame that equals `self.view.frame`. When my user "swipes", I have a **UIView** named *newView* which smoothly slides into *contentView*'s old position. The user can swipe left or right and *newView* will come in from `frame.origin.x = -320` (UISwipe direction right), or `frame.origin.x = 320` (UISwipe direction left).

Anyway.. If you view any picture/post on Instagram, you'll notice that you can hold your finger on the view and the animation is guided by your finger. If you dont pass a certain x-position on the screen with the view and release, the view will simply pop back into place. I want this type of animation with the swapping of my two **UIView**s which, dynamically, swipe until the end of an array is reached.

I understand that maybe what Im looking for is these delegation methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

But Im currently using **UISwipeGestureRecognizer**. What would this implementation look like? And no I'm not asking you to write my code for me, I just need a general idea of how this can be accomplished via UISwipeGestureRecognizer or touchEvents. Thanks!